# using jquery on javascript built table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built an table using JavaScript. However when I try to call jQuery on that table it doesnt work. I am trying to make jQuery highlight the columns of the table when I hoover with it. 
Here is my code

```js
var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

// Insert a row in the table at row index 0
var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

// Insert a cell in the row at index 0
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);

// Append a text node to the cell
var newText = document.createTextNode('New row')

// Append a text node to the cell
newCell.appendChild(newText);



//Apend new cell to same row
var newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
var newText = document.createTextNode('Nea')
newCell.appendChild(newText);


//highlight column 
$('td').on('mouseenter', function() {
  var i = $(this).parent().children().index(this);
  $('col').removeClass('hovered');
  $('col:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').addClass('hovered');
});

$('td').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('col').removeClass('hovered');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
col.hovered {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>My Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaa</td>
      <td>aaaaa</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>My footer</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Here is JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4sR2G/764/

Comment: It does work at Fiddle. jQuery is a wrapper around JS. There is no possibility of JS and jQuery basic functionality. You may mix it.

Comment: need to highlight column and row... like this
http://jsfiddle.net/Sumurai8/uzkpu/

Comment: Ah, I see. It is clear now.

Comment: col is not a class ... what you've failed to do is define any `<col>`'s

Comment: true your right guys

Comment: got it http://jsfiddle.net/4sR2G/765/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the effect using

```
<colgroup>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
    <col></col>
</colgroup>
```

From one of the examples you gave.